# How do I use Convex Hull without removing indent detail

Tags: mesh

Im trying to use the hull convex tool on a object to make the appearance smooth, but doing so removes the detail i'm trying to get on the object...Is there a way i can fix this or any alternative way

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't the clue in the name? Perhaps another tool. What kind of smoothness are you looking for?

Comment: Mesh/clean up/fill holes" then "sides" set to 0 in the operator panel?